# Number of words from a file with the Linux shell

Tags: text-processing

How do I find and many words of a file with the Linux shell?

I have

```
text
example

text
example

text
example

text
example
```

And I need

```
text
example1

text
Example2

text
example3

text
example4
```

That is, the word is located and then numbers.

Comment: I read this quickly, posted, and then deleted my answer.  Now that I'm carefully reading I don't think I understand what you are asking for.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I edited the question, and found that the in the original question the words `text` and `example*` where on two different line, shown on a single line because of poor use of markdown.

Comment: Even after your edits, it's really hard to understand exactly what you need. Maybe you could add a mock up of the output you're hoping to get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question. However provided your input example and your output example you can do something like this (just an orientation):

Your input file named "example" is as follows:

```
text
example

text
example

text
example

text
example
```

So provided that "text" can be any thing in a line, and "example" is just "example" (edit my code to fit your needs); you can match your output requirements with the following statement (not too much exhaustive however):

```
hmontoliu@ulises:/tmp$ awk 'BEGIN {c=0} {if ( $0 ~ /example/ ) {c+=1; print $0c} else print $0}'   example 
text
example1

text
example2

text
example3

text
example4
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from example you want to print lines and after that line number.

For printing line number and then lines you can use `cat` or `nl`:

```
$ cat -n test.txt 
     1  text example
     2  text example
     3  text example
     4  text example

$ nl test.txt 
     1  text example
     2  text example
     3  text example
     4  text example
```

But there is no possibility to print numbers after lines in `cat` and `nl` so you can use `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $0 "\t" NR}' test.txt 
text example    1
text example    2
text example    3
text example    4
```